# Sorting decimal data does not work properly

Tags: r

I have a data frame `Rating` with two columns `HospitalName`, `DeathRate_For_Hospital`. It looks like

```
    HospitalName    DeathRate_For_Hospital
    MGM Hospital                       9.8                    
    HNK Hospital                      10.1
Hopkins Hospital                       8.3
    Arr Medicals                      10.0
           .                            .
           .                            .
```

All I need is to get the hospital name with least `DeathRate_For_Hospital`, so I order the `DeathRate_for_Hospital` like:

```
Rating <- Rating[order(round(as.numeric( Rating$ DeathRate_For_Hospital))),]
head(Rating,1)
```

Though I converted to ascending order, I don't know why it works.

This is working good if I have only numeric values. But if their are floating values sort is not working .

Thanks

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, Order is working when the column has the Numerical values, if the column has the floating values like 9.35,10.1,8.3..etc then order is not working properly .

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, it is factor. i mean the two columns which it has is factor and factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I need is to get the hospital name with the least `DeathRate_For_Hospital`

If `with(Rating, class(DeathRate_For_Hospital))` is "numeric", you only need:

```
with(Rating, HospitalName[order(DeathRate_For_Hospital)])[1]
```

But since it gives you "factor", you need:

```
with(Rating, HospitalName[order(as.numeric(as.character(DeathRate_For_Hospital)))])[1]
```

or more efficiently:

```
numbers <- as.numeric(levels(DeathRate_For_Hospital))
with(Rating, HospitalName[order(numbers[DeathRate_For_Hospital])])[1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much